# symfony2 register/check-email template

Tags: php, symfony, twig

After registration i have an redirection to register/check-email (checkEmail.html.twig) page. This template is FOSUserBundle in vendors
How i can overwrite it with my own template? Maybe i need todo smth in my bundle? I've just started to learn symfony2
I've tried add it in `config.yml` but it doesn't works as i need:

```
registration:
    confirmation:
        template: default/confirm-email.html.twig
        enabled: true
```

What can i do with that?

Comment: You can overwrite almost any part of another bundle in your application, here is well explained how to archieve it: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/override.html

Comment: and http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/overriding_templates.html .. also why the template is not working because its not in the allowed format.. it needs to be BundleName:FolderInsideResources:file.twig format .

Comment: Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Overriding Default FOSUserBundle Templates

http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/overriding_templates.html